# Simple Date Difference Referencing Form Control

Tags: vba, ms-access, datediff

I am trying to do a simple date difference calculation that returns a Year and Month value. The code the I have now is:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate() 
Dim IntegerYears As Long 
Dim IntegerMonths As Long 

IntegerYears = DateDiff("yyyy", Me.DeemedFilingDate, Now()) 
IntegerMonths = DateDiff("m", Me.DeemedFilingDate - IntegerYears, Now()) 
Me.TimeElapsedFromFilingDate = IntegerYears & " Yr(s)." & " " & "," & " " & IntegerMonths & " Mo(s)." 

End Sub
```

At this point, I am getting an output in year/month format, but it's not correct. I am getting negative numbers, the month count goes above 12 months, and the year shows 1 year when the start date is in the previous year but a year hasn't necessarily passed. For instance, the code will return 1 year if the start date is 12/1/2017 and the current date is 3/2/2018 instead of just returning 3 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
Dim TimeElapsedMonths As Integer
Dim TimeElapsedYears As Integer
Dim TimeElapsedRemMonths As Integer

TimeElapsedMonths = DateDiff("m", Me.DeemedFilingDate, Now())
TimeElapsedRemMonths = TimeElapsedMonths Mod 12
TimeElapsedYears = Int(TimeElapsedMonths / 12)

Me.TimeElapsedFromFilingDate = TimeElapsedYears & " Yr(s)." & "," & " " & 
TimeElapsedRemMonths & " Mo(s)."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing multiple unusual things. Let me walk you through them:

You've declared `TimeElapsed` as a double, but you're setting it equal to the result of `DateDiff`, which returns a Variant(Long)

```
Dim TimeElapsed As Long
```

You need to use string delimiters in your `DateDiff` for the first argument. Also, it's lower case y, not upper case:

```
TimeElapsed = DateDiff("yyyy", Now(), Me.DeemedFilingDate)
```

This line:

```
IntegerMonths = Round(TimeElapsed - IntegerYears) * 12
```

Makes no sense to me. You're taking the time elapsed, removing the time difference between then and now in years, then rounding it, and then multiplying it by 12?

You probably want the following instead:

```
IntegerMonths = DateDiff("m", Now(), Me.DeemedFilingDate - TimeElapsed)
```

Also, VBA doesn't really do integers. All integers in VBA are really longs that get cast to an integer as needed. Using a long is more efficient, and doesn't take more memory.

Final result:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Dim IntegerYears As Long
    Dim IntegerMonths As Long

    IntegerYears = DateDiff("yyyy", Now(), Me.DeemedFilingDate)
    IntegerMonths =  DateDiff("m", DateAdd("yyyy", IntegerYears *-1, Now()), Me.DeemedFilingDate)
    Me.TimeElapsedFromFilingDate = IntegerYears & " Years " & IntegerMonths & " Months"
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using the code that you provided but am still getting odd results. For instance, I would expect that the difference between 10/1/2014 and today would be 4 years and 5 months. However, the code is returning -4 years and -41 months. The month count should never exceed 12 months. I can resolve the (-) issue by taking the absolute value, but that won't fix the month issue.  Any advice on that problem?

Comment: I made this adjustment which corrects the negative values, but I am still getting a month count that goes well over 12: 

`Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Dim IntegerYears As Long
    Dim IntegerMonths As Long

    IntegerYears = DateDiff("yyyy", Me.DeemedFilingDate, Now())
    IntegerMonths = DateDiff("m", Me.DeemedFilingDate - IntegerYears, Now())
    Me.TimeElapsedFromFilingDate = IntegerYears & " Yr(s)." & " " & "," & " " & IntegerMonths & " Mo(s)."
End Sub`

Comment: I've made a simple error: you have to cast the long back to a year:

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I'm getting an error for this part of the code: `IntegerMonths = DateDiff("m", DateAdd("yyyy", Now(), IntegerYears * -1), Me.DeemedFilingDate)`.It's and invalid procedure call or argument error.

Comment: oh, sorry, don't have a decent test setup here. Made a simple ordering error.

Comment: I am getting negatives again and the count isn't exactly right. It's putting the difference between 5/1/2017 and this month to 1 year and 2 months instead of 10months.